# Difference between Garbage Collection and a For Loop destroying objetcs

Tags: c#

I have this code that creates 5500 objetcs of a class and then it outputs the the total allocated bytes and total memory so that way I can see the changes in the allocated bytes.
I also have a destructor so I can see approximately when the Garbage Collection occurs.
From the output on the console, I can see that the GC does not occur after each iteration of the for loop and I heard from somewhere that a for loop constructs and destructs objects after each iteration(obviously if the loop creates objects in its body).
Now I am wondering if the action of the for loop of constructing and destructing objects after each iteration is not Garbage Collection(It is not done by the process of Garbage Collection), then what is It?
How does the for loop destruct the object, considering the Object is stored in the heap?
How is the object removed from the heap, after each iteration?

```
class Destruct {

    int x;
    int g;

    public Destruct(int i, int h) {
        x = i;
        g = h;
    }

    ~Destruct() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Destructor called for {x}");
    }


    public void Generator(int o,int l) {
        new Destruct(o,l);
    }

}


class one {

    static void Main() {
        int count = 1;
        Destruct ob = new Destruct(0,0);
        long tot;
        long mem;

        for (int i = 1, y=1; i <= 5500; i++,y++) {
            ob.Generator(i,y);
            tot = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes();
            mem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine(count+"   "+tot+"  "+mem+"   "+(tot-mem));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");

    }

}
```

Comment: The garbage collector does not run each time something goes out of scope. If you want to test that behavior you need to force it to run, using `GC.Collect()` Normally it runs only when it deems it necessary, i.e. when a lot of memory is being used.

Comment: I know that, that is why I am asking the question, I need to know how does a forloop destruct an object.

Comment: A for-loop does *not* destruct anything.  GC is completely automatic, trying to help is always a mistake.

Comment: As I know, there is nothing special in loops in relation with GC. Are you sure that you heard exactly about GC and not about the life span for objects, created inside loop?

Comment: If you want to manually control when all of your objects are released from memory rather than letting the GC handle it then use C or C++.  Using a GCed language fundamentally means giving up a lot of control over how objects are destroyed.

Comment: I mean, the objets in each iteration of the loop go out of scope nd hence they are destroyed right? I ma trying to understnad how are they destroyed?

Comment: "I mean, the objets in each iteration of the loop go out of scope nd hence they are destroyed right?" No. The objects _go out of scope_, which means they are eligible for garbage collection, but that does not mean that they are immediately collected, only that they can be collected. When they are actually collected is rather random. You could call `GC.Collect();GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` to force it, but you should not normally do that.

Comment: Yes, I get It, but where do those objects "go"? don't  they get destroyed somehow?

Comment: I think this should answer all your questions about GC: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6179/garbage-collection-and-c